# Responsive two column Footer

Tags: html, css, layout

I need a responsive two column footer. However, the thing doesnt turn out to be responsive.I've shown it in here.
http://jsfiddle.net/fVBaB/
The CSS code is here...

```
 #leftf
{
width:46%;
display:block;
float:left;
margin-bottom:20px;
border: 1px solid grey;
padding:18px;
height:100px;
}

 #rightf
{
height:100px;
padding:18px;
width:46%;
display:block;
float:right;
margin-bottom:20px;
border: 1px solid grey;
}

 #bottomline
{
width:100%;
display:block;
bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get your question, could you explain some more ?

Comment: I just need my footer to be responsive and in same line. However, just look in the fiddle, zoom in or out, the footer doesn't turn out to be responsive and the things just kinda gets overlapped and not shown how it is supposed to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your mixing percentages and pixels in the width - you're also using `block` and not `inline-block`. Change your CSS to:

```
#leftf
{
width:46%;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
margin-bottom:20px;
padding:2%;
height:100px;
}

#rightf
{
height:100px;
padding:2%;
width:46%;
display:inline-block;
float:right;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

#bottomline
{
width:100%;
display:block;
bottom:0px;
}
```

I've also removed the border from `#leftf` and `#rightf` as this was adding a pixel each. Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/MY5VE/.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need those borders. And still on my Laptop the things get overlapped.

Comment: Change the padding to 1% each instead of 2% - does that work?

Comment: It doesnt come out to be perfectly responsive. But manageable for now. Thanks!